# Showing cross symbol in html

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've a wired issue. Im working on the html of a new website. Its showing cross symbol instead of blank spaces. Screenshots attached.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The html behind this cross is:

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

Chrome inspect of the cross symbol:

[image]

I googled and found out that its something to do with chrome and font-family im using. Im using

```
'vag_roundedregular', 'Varela Round', sans-serif
```

If i comment this font-family, cross sign disappear. This is only visible on chrome.

Any help is highly appreciated. Please let me know if you guyz need information.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache completely already? This sounds like Chrome is simply messing up displaying the space character of a certain font, so maybe the downloaded version of that font it uses got corrupted somehow … Do you see this problem in Chrome on other machines as well?

Comment: tried all, all cache refreshed, used incognito window. still same issue

Comment: Is `vag_roundedregular` a local font file? If so, try re-installing it.

Comment: files are placed locally and included in style.css

Comment: It is likely that the font face you're using is causing the issue, where the non-breaking white space character is assigned a glyph, instead of a blank space. Have you tried redownloading and reinstalling the font?

Answer (score 1):

Use `&thinsp;` instead of `&nbsp;`

or set CSS as:

```
.clear{opacity:0;}
```

Comment: Thnx for your response. clear { opacity:0; } works. But there's any problem im using CMS and there's hugh amount of content generating from the CMS that also shows the cross symbol. sometime in empty <p> or <div> tags. like this <p>&nbsp;</p> and it'll take too much of time to replace all &nbsp to &thinsp as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

What do you see in the chrome inspector? Anyway, you could add a class to the container div and set

`visibility: hidden`

in the css.
But first let me now the inspector result please, as there could be a better solution for that problem, hopefully.

Comment: Updated my question with a screenshot of chrome inspect. I cannot hide the div with symbol. There are places where i need to intentionally add spaces using &nbsp;

Comment: added some more screenshots to better explain the situation

Comment: with visibility hidden is different from display none and it should just make the crosses transparent without modify the general space occupied

Comment: is it possible to add visibility:hidden for all empty elements like <p>&nbsp;</p> or <div>&nbsp;</div> ?

Comment: i don't think so. One thing that you could do tho, is set visibility:hidden to p,div and remember to add a different class to all other p and div with visibility:visible. 
But it is not really a good way to code. 
Just as suggestion, what if you try with a similar font or with a font hosted by google or similar services? maybe you will find a font that is similar to the one you want and you don't have to add walkarounds like this

Comment: look at this post, it is a free version very similar to the font you want to use: http://marktyrrell.com/tag/font-face/

Answer (score -2):

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/nbsp/thinsp/g' *.tpl {} \;
```

Comment: Insted for only posting code please explain what the code does, also put your code in code block.